# MS Jet database on windows 8

Tags: excel, vba, windows-8, excel-2013

I have a Excel macro, which works on my Windows 7 computer but not on my Window 8.
On the Windows 8 computer I have tried with both Excel 2013 and Excel 2010 and it gives the same error. 
Runtime  Error 3706.

This is my connection open string.

```
Myconnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & Myworkbook & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;" & _
    "Persist Security Info=False"
```

Is there an other version to use on Windows 8 for this.

Comment: Do you know if its a 32 bit or 54 bit OS?

Comment: You might need to install the provider using this package: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: @ElectricLlama You might want to post this as an actual answer. Unfortunately, it did not solve my problem...

Comment: Perhaps you could find out which providers are installed by following the steps on this page: http://www.jameswiseman.com/blog/2010/07/13/windows-universal-data-link-udl-files-and-conection-testing/. I don't know how difficult Windows 8 makes it but give it a try and see if you can observe what providers are installed. There also complications around 32/64 but but first tell us if you are running 32 or 64 bit windows 8

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem on an Excel "program" that I built for Excel 2003 on a Windows XP machine.
It won't connect to its Access database on a Windows 8.1 (x64) machine, stating that it is missing that OLEDB driver.

For me, a somewhat dirty switch to another driver fixed it.
Using my old parameters, I could change over to

```
Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
```

which works just as well and seems to be an easy fix.
(Therefore, just replace the old "Jet.OLEDB.4.0" with "ACE.OLEDB.12.0" and you should be fine).